# Gerrit: switch merged dependency to master changes

Tags: git, gerrit

I have review A that has been dependent on the review B. Review B has been merged.

My goal is to get rid of dependencies from review A, namely remove B, then switch to the last master changes.

I am a new in such staff. Will be good to know, in which way it can be achived(Usefull link or some manual).

I've tried to find in the http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Gerrit/Advanced_usage, but I didn't find any related doc.

Comment: You can remove commit B with a new commit, and then rebase commit A on that

Answer (score 1):

If Review B has been merged, the easiest solution is to click the `Rebase` button on the Review page for change A.  This will rebase A on to the tips of master for you automatically.

If you don't have permissions to do this (don't see the `Rebase` button on the change page), or just want to do it by hand, it is fairly easy:

1. In your local sandbox, `git fetch && git reset --hard && git checkout origin/master` (assuming you are using the `master` branch - change the branch name otherwise)
2. From the Review page for change A, copy the Download->cherry-pick text
3. Paste this into your local sandbox
4. If there are any merge conflicts, resolve them
5. Upload this new commit back to Gerrit using the same process you did to create changes A and B.

Your new version of change A will be at tips of master and won't depend on the outdated change B any more.